# Rewrite Rule gives 500 Error

Tags: mod-rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^files/(.*) files/index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am trying to rewrite everything in the files directory to **index.php** which is also in the files directory. The page displays but always gives a **500 error** , can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in the same order:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files [NC]
RewriteRule ^(files)/.* $1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Works perfectly , I also fixed something in my file , but your code works perfect , thank you very much !!